# Show that $\int_E f = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i m(\{x \in E \mid f(x)=c_i\})$ when $f(E)$ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f :E \to [0, +\infty]$ be measurable. Show that $$\int_E f = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i m(\{x \in E \mid f(x)=c_i\})$$ when $f(E)$ is countable.

I suppose I have to use simple functions here to show this? The rhs of the equality seems to be the integral of some simple function over $E$ and $E_i= \{x \in E \mid f(x)=c_i\}$. Since $f$ is non-negative I have that $$\int_E f = \sup \left\{\int_Es \mid 0\le s\le f \right\}$$ where $s$ is a simple function. So in essence I have to show that $$\sup \left\{\int_Es \mid 0\le s\le f \right\} = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i m(\{x \in E \mid f(x)=c_i\})?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f(E)$ is countable we have

$$ f = \sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i \chi_{E_i},$$

where $\{c_i\}$ is an enumeration of $f(E)$ and $E_i = f^{-1} (c_i)$. Then $f = \lim f_n$, where $\{ f_n\}$ is the increasing sequence (since $c_i \ge 0$)

$$ f_n = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \chi_{E_i}.$$

By monotone convergence theorem,

$$ \int_E f = \lim_n \int_E f_n = \lim_n \sum_{i=1}^n c_i m(E_i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i m(E_i). $$